# NHibernate 1st level cache

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, first-level-cache

Context: I am working on a .NET 3.5 Windows application that crashes once RAM has been completely filled by NHibernate 1st level caching.

Question 1: Does NHibernate's 1st level caching algorithm perform memory checks to ensure sufficient space exists?

Question 2: When using the Evict method, are the following pseudo code steps correct?

1 - session.Query

2 - save query results

3 - session.Evict

4 - return saved results

**Update**

In the context where sessions are created at the start of the application and disposed off only once application ends, I wish to control NHibernate's first level cache size. NHibernate documentation explains in details how cache works and how to manage it but makes no mention of **cache size**, which is an issue in my case.

Question 3: Is it possible to know the cache size of session (to subsequently clear it if needed)? Alternatively, is possible to set a limit on the size of the cache Nhibernate can use application wide?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should not use single session for your app. Usually you should create one per single unit of work. There multiple examples on session management in desktop apps:
[one](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/currentsessioncontext-for-desktop-development.html)
[two](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx)